# How to verify a network device has an IP address in VxWorks

Tags: ip, vxworks

I am trying to verify the Ethernet devices on a device are working correctly. I'm running the command:

```
ifconfig("interfaceName dhcp")
```

for each ethernet interface.

What I would also like to do is verify that each device got an ip address as well. I know I can just run 'ifconfig' by itself and look at the output, but I'm writing automated test code. So is there a function that can return the ip address of a specific interface in VxWorks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe ifAddrGet() in ifLib.h may be what you're looking for. The first argument takes an interface name and the second argument takes a buffer, into which the address will be returned.

I haven't tested the following on an actual target, but it should be a start toward what you need:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inetLib.h"
#include "ifLib.h"

void print_if_address (void);

void print_if_address ()
{
    char if_name[] = "dhcp";
    char ip_address[INET_ADDR_LEN] = {0};

    ifAddrGet (if_name, ip_address);

    printf ("%s\n", ip_address);
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble including ifLib.h in my code. Has this library been obsoleted?